# SQL to LINQ - Left Join two conditions

Tags: c#, linq

How can I convert this outer left join to LINQ?

```
    SELECT *  from table1 t1
      left join table2 t2 on  t1.code = t2.code AND  t2.id ='xxxxx'
       WHERE t1.someId = 2
```

I'm trying something like this:

```
from t1 in db.table1
join t2 in db.table2 on t1.Code equals t2.Code
into oj
from sub in oj.DefaultIfEmpty()
where t1.someId == 2
where (sub.id == 'xxxx')
```

but not all rows from left table are being returned. The where clauses i think are applied after the join.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Comment: For multiple parameters like that you have to create anonymous types with the values as the keys to compare `on new {t1.Code, id ="xxxxx"} equals new {t2.Code, t2.id}`.

Comment: still not working because sub.id  is only on one table.... i would like to apply the t2.id ='xxxxx' with the join and not after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var res=(from t1 in table1.Where(x=>x.someId==2)
         join t2 in table2.Where(y=>y.id==xxxx)
         on t1.code = t2.code
         into r 
         from t3 in r.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new {t1,t3}).ToList();
```